# Using a gradient on view of appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

Hello, I try to accomplish a gradient for a view like described in the following picture.

[image]

I achieve not excate the solution and I don't know what I do wrong.

I put a gradient like the following

```
backgroundGradient:{         
type:'liniar',
    colors: [ { color:'#008DB8', 
                offset: 0 .0}, 
              { color: '#9BD36E', offset: 1.0 }], 
    startPoint: { x: 0, y: 0 },         
    endPoint: { x: '80%', y: '80%' },
    backfillEnd: true}
```

The result is not the expecte view. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled 'linear'.

Review the documentation here for a good working example.

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest//?mobile=/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow-method-popToRootWindow